# Alert triggered node name is not specifying in the alert being received when more than one is triggered

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I have Configured an alert for node memory usage in prometheus. My alert template is as follows:

```
- alert: NodeMemory Usage(development)
      annotations:
        description: '{{$labels.instance}} Memory usage is critical (current value is: {{ $value }})'
        summary: High Memory  usage detected
      expr: |
        1 - sum by(node) ((node_memory_MemFree{job="node-exporter"} + node_memory_Cached{job="node-exporter"} + node_memory_Buffers{job="node-exporter"}) * on(namespace, pod) group_left(node) node_namespace_pod:kube_pod_info:) / sum by(node) (node_memory_MemTotal{job="node-exporter"}* on(namespace, pod) group_left(node) node_namespace_pod:kube_pod_info:)  > 0.70
      for: 1s
      labels:
        severity: warning
```

I receives the name of the node with in the alert, when the threshold exceeds for a single node(node name here is nodes-3z4c), as follows:

```
[FIRING:1]  (NodeMemory Usage(development) nodes-3z4c monitoring/k8s warning)

Memory usage is critical (current value is: 0.7148033249432908)
```

But the issue is, when multiple nodes exceeds the threshold value, The name of the multiple nodes are not specifying in the alert notification and getting a notification as follows:

```
[FIRING:4] NodeMemory Usage (monitoring/k8s)
Memory usage is critical (current value is: 0.7319404231240473)
Memory usage is critical (current value is: 0.7856648253333621)
```

Can some one help me to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with how you defined the alert. If you look at it in the Alertmanager UI, you'll see that all labels are there.

It's either the [template you use](https://prometheus.io/blog/2016/03/03/custom-alertmanager-templates/) (if Alertmanager is sending the message directly) or whatever webhook handler you're using that's only keeping the common labels and dropping everything else.

Comment: Okay,Thank you for the response. I got the idea.